# Update mutiple records in database MVC 5 EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, crud

Good evening,
Now I'll describe my situation:
Here is my Model:

```
[Table("Items")]
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Generated { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string UrlSeo { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I;m implementing CRUD operations to DB records, but I need implement one more Action, I need to Update for example **UrlSeo** property in  selected records in one action.
So here is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<CheckBoxes.Models.Item>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Items";
}
<dv class="page-header">
<h3>Items</h3>
</dv>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeUrl", "Items", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group-sm">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.TextBox("urlSeo", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>

    </p>
</div>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" />
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Generated)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UrlSeo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsActive)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" value="@item.Id" />
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Generated)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UrlSeo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsActive)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
}
@section Scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/toastr")
<!--მასიური  წაშლა-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#checkAll").click(function () {
            $(".checkBox").prop('checked',
                $(this).prop('checked'));
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

And Finally My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ChangeUrl(string urlSeo, string[] id)
    {
        foreach (var itemId in id)
        {
            Item item = await db.Items.FindAsync(itemId);
            item.UrlSeo = urlSeo;
            db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(item).Property(x => x.Generated).IsModified = false;
            db.Entry(item).Property(x => x.Content).IsModified = false;
            db.Entry(item).Property(x => x.IsActive).IsModified = false;
            db.Entry(item).Property(x => x.Price).IsModified = false;
            db.Entry(item).Property(x => x.Quantity).IsModified = false;
        }
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

**Now Question**
How to pass all checked items to controller and input from field.
I home someone will help me.

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038736/post-checked-checkboxes-to-controller-action-without-using-html-helper-like-html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543414/mvc-checkboxlist-model-binding-with-non-boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where was problem in view here is necessary give name for checkbox, witch  equals part of controller.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <th>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" value="@item.Id" name="id" />
        </th>
```

Everything worked fine, yes one more thing, better to use:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

So this is working solution.